# Updating the changes to an file open in a text editor, using Python

Tags: python, file, io

My problem is that when I make changes to a file using a Python program while I also have it open on my screen, I cannot see the changes without closing the file and opening again. I need a way for the program to update the file while I am looking at it. This is critical to my program.

It is critical that it updates because I am making something similar to a scripting language that would have to respond to each command right after it is typed. It would give a result on the next line of the notepad file.

Important Notes:

- I know how to modify a file.
- By file, I mean notepad.
- When I say that I have a file open, I don't mean that the Python program has the file open with the `Open()` function. I mean that I, the user, have the file open on the screen to where I can see it.
- Please don't ask for actual code. I have not started creating anything. That would be pointless because everything relies on this concept that I am about to ask.

Comment: Reloading a modified file is a feature of the program having the file opened and not the program changing it. There are editors which can do that.

Comment: @Klaus D. Can you give me some examples of these editors?

Comment: I think sublime text 3 is a example

Comment: Take a look at `Notepad ++`. Notepad ++ will inform you that a change has been made to a file and will ask you if you want to view the updated change.

Comment: Also this kind of question is not for stack overflow. There are stack sites where you can ask this kind of question.

Comment: @Sierra Mountain Tech Why is it not for stack overflow

Comment: For this kind of question you might want to ask it on [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). This stack overflow site is for codding problems rather than software related question on features a particular software might have.

Comment: @Sierra Mountain Tech Okay, sorry. I thought this was a coding question when I asked it.

Comment: Also maybe add some context as to why it is critical for program to update what you are seeing every time an edit is made to it. That might provide some context that will help someone answer.

Comment: I have also noticed by reading some of you other post you seam very concerned about getting down voted. Here is a link [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that will give you the guidelines you need to help improve your questions. This will also help a lot with not getting down votes [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sierra Mountain Tech Thanks, I'll try these.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: no, this question is not appropriate for Meta. Meta is for questions about Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: @halfer: Then can you recommend the correct site. I know this question really is not for this site.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: well, if the question is how to use code in order to get a text editor to reload its contents, then it is fine here. However, it is based on a misunderstanding, I think - auto-reload is a feature of text editors, and so contrary to the OP's post, the question really _would_ be about using file operations to modify the text file on disk. In any case, since the question has no code in it, it is probably "too broad" anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the program you're using. There are some which reloads the file if there has been some changes; others that simply don't allow other process to edit the file. 
As a personal experience for text editors, Notepad++ allows python to edit an open file and detects automatically any edit and asks the user if he wants to reload the file or not, meanwhile basic notepads (like the ones built in the OS) that deny opening the file in write mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's not in your responsibility to ensure that the text editor refreshes its buffers upon a write. If your program is meant to be used with a text editor, consider writing an extension plugin instead.

In Vim you can reload the buffer with `:e`. In Emacs you can do the same thing using `M-x revert-buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

operating system handle file change notifications

or

maby this works:

```
import os
import time

filename = "example.txt"

# Get the current time
current_time = time.time()

# Update the last access time of the file to the current time
os.utime(filename, (current_time, current_time))

# Print the new last access time of the file
new_access_time = os.path.getatime(filename)
print(f"New access time: {new_access_time} ({time.ctime(new_access_time)})")
```